# Using AsyncTask in combination with n-tier model

Tags: android, n-tier-architecture, android-asynctask

I think I might be on the wrong track here so I'm posting this to find out.

I'm developing an android app that uses a number of rest-service requests to load its data.

I arranged my code following the n-tier pattern: domain layer (domain) / webservice access layer (dal) / business logic layer (service) / ui layer (ui)

From my activity I start an AsyncTask to load the items from the service layer. While the items are loading I show a progress dialog with a continious looping circle icon. This isn't very user friendly, so I would like to display progress in stead via a progress indicator.

I can easily alter my dal so that it first gets a list of id's of the items to fetch, and then fetches them one at a time, in stead of in bulk. This way I could report progress to the user, while updating the ui everytime a new item (or 2 or more) is loaded.

The problem is that I don't know how to go about this. All the examples of AsyncTask work on the principle that everything happens within a class that inherits AsyncTask and this has to be executed from the ui thread.

Is there anyone who can provide a short code example on how I should define my AsyncTask class, and how I would be able to report progress from within the data access layer to the UI?

If I put all the code in the ui, there would be no problem, but that's not very good practice imo.

Code example of what I want to do:

Somewhere in MainApplication I keep a list of orders:

```
public List<Order> orders = null;
```

My activity calls the AsyncTask and starts it:

OrderActivity.java

```
public void loadOrdersAsync() {
    // Create async task instance
    OrderLoaderAsyncTask loader = new OrderLoaderAsyncTask();

    // Start loading
    loader.doInBackground();
}
```

OrderLoadAsyncTask.java

```
public class OrderLoaderAsyncTask  extends AsyncTask {
    @Override
    public Integer doInBackground(Context.... params) {
        OrderService service = new OrderService();
        MainApplication.orders = service.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        // Update progress bar
        updateProgressBar(values);
    }
}
```

OrderService.java

```
public class OrderService {
    public List<Order> getAll() {
        // Check to see if we have a cached version
        // If we don't, we fetch the orders from REST webservice
        OrderRepository repository = new OrderRepository();

        // Get list of ID's to fetch
        List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>;
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>;
        ids = repository.getIDs();

        // For each id, fetch order from webservice
        for (Integer id : ids) {
            Order order = repository.getOneById(id);

            orders.add(order);

            // Report progress, but how?
        }

        return orders;
    }
}
```

Now in my service I can keep track of the progress, but how do I report this progress to the UI without moving the logic to build the orderslist to my AsyncTask class? How do I report progress from within my service layer? Or even from within my repository layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way of doing that with precision, REST services are kind of request-reply, you'll receive data only after its all loaded in data layer inside REST server.

I'll do it with a progress bar, updating each 500mS with a Timer. Just have in mind that Timer fires another thread, so you need to update UI inside a runOnUiThread() method of your activity.

Example code:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

    private Timer myTimer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TimerMethod();
            }

        }, 0, 500);  // 500mS starting with no delay
    }

    private void TimerMethod()
    {
            // this runs each time Timer fires
        this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
    }

    private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            // do something with my progress bar
        UpdateMyProgressBar();

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a tad resource consuming? Further more, I think that it goes against the nature of AsyncTask to do it that way...

Comment: This might not be a very good practice, but it perfectly fits what I want to do, so I'm going to accept this as well.

Comment: I've bet is less consuming than having to create an AsyncTask over and over again, remember that AsyncTask can be fired one time only. With a timer, you can periodically poll your datasource (whatever it is, rest server, JDBC connection, you name it) and post your progress. Take a look at AsyncTask source code, is not far from what I've described up here, instead of timers they've used handlers.

Comment: @ruhalde Java Timer is discouraged on Android, use a Handler instead: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Comment: @Sander_Versluys, As far as I know, Handler always run in an UI Thread inside a queue, Timer can run in its own thread. How would you do an async reading from a database periodically updating UI?

Answer (score 2):

First thing I would like to say is that in my opinion the n-tier architecture you're describing is a bit overkill for most mobile apps. It doesn't mean you don't need to layer your app and separate responsibilities. It's just that the tiers your describing are indeed good architectural layers for bigger enterprise applications but I find applying those strictly on Android code-wise results in fighting the system when there's in fact (a better) Android way of doing those things.

For example, one thing your fighting is that you would like to completely separate your 'service' from your activity but still want to update something in the UI. That's impossible.

Android uses dependency injection extensively. You'll notice that Context is a often the first argument for various methods. Just to show that if you want to completely separate something from the UI you have to create a new 'Context' to work from. Android provides this with services. This way you can do work completely separate from the UI and use intents for messaging between the background service and the UI.

But I understand that for some apps or beginning Android developers services seem a bit complicated (they are not really). Just wanted to point out that services are the only real way to create a thread that's not tied to an activity. Some people use tricks by overriding the Application class and mapping soft references of activities and threads. This way when configuration changes occur (orientation change for example) threads don't get killed and can get a reference to the newly created activity instance. These tricks are in my opinion anti-patterns.

Back to your problem.

I suggest keeping it simple. Just know that starting a new thread from the UI implies the thread can get killed when the configuration changes and you can loose data already retrieved from the network.

1. Write a http utility class which wrap some post/get functionality and probably set some http headers for every request.
2. Write a simple service layer. These classes contain methods were each methods perfoms one simple task or rest request.
3. In your activity use an AsyncTask which combines some service methods and provide feedback to the UI

You can improve on this later if you like and move the logic from the AsyncTask to its own real background Service and do some intermediate messaging with Intents and BroadcastReceivers.

But for your convenience a simplified example of doing it the easy way without services:

```
public class OrderActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new OrderLoaderTask().execute();
    }

    class Order {
        // Add some data
    }

    class OrderService {

        public List<Integer> getOrderIds() {
            List<Integer> ids = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7});
            return ids;         
        }

        public Order getOrder(int id) {
            // Do real http request through some utility class
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new Order();
        }

    }

    class OrderLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<Order>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(TestAndroidActivity.this, "loading", "loading");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            progressDialog.setMessage(String.format("loading (%s/%s)", values[0], values[1]));
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Order> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            OrderService service = new OrderService();

            List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

            List<Integer> ids = service.getOrderIds();
            for (int i=0; i<ids.size(); i++) {
                orders.add(service.getOrder(ids.get(i)));
                publishProgress(i+1, ids.size());
            }
            return orders;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Order> result) {
            if (result != null) {
                // Do something with the results!
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Note: just create new android project copy this code, fix imports and run!

If you want to 'reuse' the code in the AsyncTask, move to it's own file, make class public and override methods... Again, there alway some glue code or interface needed between threads.

```
new OrderLoaderTask() {

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer[] values) {
        // Update progress
    };

    protected void onPostExecute(List<Order> result) {
        // Do something
    };

}.execute();
```

Comment: The last code sample is exactly how I'm doing it now. But the problem with this is that the method to fetch the orders is not stored in the service and is therefor hard to re-use. Even more so, my application caches everything locally in cache files, so the service also needs to take that in account. I think I'm going to take a look at what services can mean for my application.

Comment: Do you need the code in more than one place? If so, make the AsyncTask public and put in own file, use an anonymous AsyncTask in each Activity you need this functionality en override onPostExecute and onProgessUpdate for code unique to each Activity...

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask has a function called on progress update, that allows you to update the UI thread with your progress. This is designed to do exactly what you are describing.

Comment: As for code examples, the documentation here is implementing that http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I know that AsyncTask has that function. But say AsyncTask calls for a service layer function (that is on an instance of the service class) in its dobackgroundwork method. The service layer in turn calls for a function in the data access layer. How am I going to update progress in the top class (in ui that is) from my data access function?

Answer (score 1):

I don't encourage to go fetch objects one by one cause it will overload your database if you have a lot of records. Consider using paging for that (only load if the user actually sees the item on the screen).

What you can do to speed things up is to load a minimum of data (only title and description for example) to show in the list, and fetch the rest later if more info is requested.

Comment: Both solutions don't really work for me. It's not just orders I need to fetch, but also a list of order states, customers, addresses, ... The service only allows me to either fetch a list of ID's for each record, or fetch the entire thing. I can however restrict the number of items it fetches in one request. In any case, the orders screen shows quite a lot of information, so the bare minimum requires quite a lot of requests.

Comment: Okay, so I've figured out a way to fetch them 5 (or any other number) at a time, so, 4 consecutive requests if there are 20 orders. That way I can update the UI progressbar and start showing orders as they roll in. But that still leaves the question of how to invoke onProgressUpdate from the service (or dal) layer that is actually performing the requests.